# Translating 3D objects with WebGL and glMatrix

Tags: javascript, webgl

I want to translate two 3D objects separately in WebGl, right now my code changes only the position and rotation of the camera.  I'm using glMatrix for vector math."buffers" is an array with the object data. 
buffers[0] and buffers[1] are two separate objects. The translation and rotation are done in drawScene function

```
function drawScene(gl, programInfo, buffers, deltaTime) {
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);  // Clear to black, fully opaque
    gl.clearDepth(1.0);                 // Clear everything
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);           // Enable depth testing
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);            // Near things obscure far things
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    var fieldOfView = 45 * Math.PI / 180; 
    var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    var zNear = 0.1;
    var zFar = 100.0;
    var projectionMatrix = mat4.create();

    mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix,fieldOfView,aspect,zNear,zFar);

    modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();

    // Camera Movement
    mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix,modelViewMatrix,[-0.0 + cubeTranslate, 0.0, -6.0]);
    mat4.rotate(modelViewMatrix,modelViewMatrix,cubeRotation,[0, 0, 1]);



    for( i = 0; i < 2; i++ ){

        var numComponents = 3;
        var type = gl.FLOAT;
        var normalize = false;
        var stride = 0;
        var offset = 0;
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[i].position);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(
            programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition,
            numComponents,
            type,
            normalize,
            stride,
            offset);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(
            programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition);

        var numComponents = 4;
        var type = gl.FLOAT;
        var normalize = false;
        var stride = 0;
        var offset = 0;
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[i].color);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(
            programInfo.attribLocations.vertexColor,
            numComponents,
            type,
            normalize,
            stride,
            offset);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(
            programInfo.attribLocations.vertexColor);


        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[i].indices);

        gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);


        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
            programInfo.uniformLocations.projectionMatrix,
            false,
            projectionMatrix);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
            programInfo.uniformLocations.modelViewMatrix,
            false,
            modelViewMatrix);


        var vertexCount = 36;
        var type = gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT;
        var offset = 0;
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, vertexCount, type, offset);

    }
    cubeRotation += deltaTime;
    cubeTranslate += 0.01
}
```

Comment: check out youtube.com/watch?v=3yLL9ADo-ko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be structured to compute matrices for each object separately

A typical program is

```
renderloop
  set viewport
  clear
  compute projection matrix
  compute view matrix
  for each object
    use program for object
    set buffers and attributes (or vertex array object)
    compute a modelView matrix
    set uniforms 
    draw
```

In your case you have this outside the `for each object` loop

```
mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix,modelViewMatrix,[-0.0 + cubeTranslate, 0.0, -6.0]);
mat4.rotate(modelViewMatrix,modelViewMatrix,cubeRotation,[0, 0, 1]);
```

That's computing a camera matrix really. To get view matrix take the inverse

```
m4.invert(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix);
```

Then inside your loop start with that matrix

```
for each object

     const mat = mat4.clone(modelViewMatrix);

     // now do something specific for each this object
     // for example
     mat4.translate(mat, mat, [objectNdx, 0, 0]);
```

Honestly I'd rename your matrices like this

```
   camera = mat4.create();

    // Camera Movement
    mat4.translate(camera,camera,[-0.0 + cubeTranslate, 0.0, -6.0]);
    mat4.rotate(camera,camera,cubeRotation,[0, 0, 1]);

    view = mat4.create();
    mat4.invert(view, camera);

    modelViewMatrix = mat4.create();

    for( i = 0; i < 2; i++ ){

        mat4.copy(modelViewMatrix, view);

        // now manipulate the matrix in ways specific to this model
        // example
        mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix, [i, 0, 0]);
```

You might find [this article helpful](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html)

Note that often the "compute modelView matrix" part is separated into a [scene graph](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-scene-graph.html) or at least partially separated. the scene graph returns "world matrices" which are then combined with the view matrix either in code or in the shader.