# Make 3DSierpinskiTriangle spin

Tags: javascript, html

How to make 3DSierpinskiTriangle Spin. I have provided with html and JavaScript code below. You need to add this [common folder](http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/~ashaw8/cs4722-01-Summer18/assignments/Common/Common.zip) and it .js files to make it work. It would be very help you anyone can solve this.
....................................................................................................................................................

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>3D Sierpinski Gasket</title>


    <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 vPosition;
        attribute vec3 vColor;
        varying vec4 color;

        void
        main()
        {
        gl_Position = vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
        color = vec4(vColor, 1.0);
        }
    </script>

    <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;

        varying vec4 color;

        void
        main()
        {
        gl_FragColor = color;
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Common/initShaders.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Common/MV.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="3DSierpinskiTriangle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512" height="512">
        Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
"use strict";

var canvas;
var gl;


var points = [];
var colors = [];

var NumTimesToSubdivide = 3;

window.onload = function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
    if (!gl) { alert("WebGL isn't available"); }

    //
    //  Initialize our data for the Sierpinski Gasket
    //

    // First, initialize the vertices of our 3D gasket
    // Four vertices on unit circle
    // Intial tetrahedron with equal length sides

    var vertices = [
        vec3(0.0000, 0.0000, -1.0000),
        vec3(0.0000, 0.9428, 0.3333),
        vec3(-0.8165, -0.4714, 0.3333),
        vec3(0.8165, -0.4714, 0.3333)
    ];

    divideTetra(vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[2], vertices[3],
        NumTimesToSubdivide);

    //
    //  Configure WebGL
    //
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    // enable hidden-surface removal

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers

    var program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // Create a buffer object, initialize it, and associate it with the
    //  associated attribute variable in our vertex shader

    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

    render();
};

function triangle(a, b, c, color) {

    // add colors and vertices for one triangle

    var baseColors = [
        vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
        vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
        vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    ];

    colors.push(baseColors[color]);
    points.push(a);
    colors.push(baseColors[color]);
    points.push(b);
    colors.push(baseColors[color]);
    points.push(c);
}

function tetra(a, b, c, d) {
    // tetrahedron with each side using
    // a different color

    triangle(a, c, b, 0);
    triangle(a, c, d, 1);
    triangle(a, b, d, 2);
    triangle(b, c, d, 3);
}

function divideTetra(a, b, c, d, count) {
    // check for end of recursion

    if (count === 0) {
        tetra(a, b, c, d);
    }

    // find midpoints of sides
    // divide four smaller tetrahedra

    else {
        var ab = mix(a, b, 0.5);
        var ac = mix(a, c, 0.5);
        var ad = mix(a, d, 0.5);
        var bc = mix(b, c, 0.5);
        var bd = mix(b, d, 0.5);
        var cd = mix(c, d, 0.5);

        --count;

        divideTetra(a, ab, ac, ad, count);
        divideTetra(ab, b, bc, bd, count);
        divideTetra(ac, bc, c, cd, count);
        divideTetra(ad, bd, cd, d, count);
    }
}


function render() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, points.length);
}
```

Comment: Please add tag `WebGL`. Add a [uniform matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/uniformMatrix) to vertex shader, multiply it with the vertices position. You are working on WebGL, you HAVE to deal with matrix anyways. Just continue on your tutorial and don't try to run before you could walk.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460010)

Answer (score 0):

```
function setup() { createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight); background(0); } function draw() { fill("#0002") noStroke() rect(0,0,width,height) recursivePyramid() } function dot(x, y) { this.x = x this.y = y this.plot = function() { fill("white") rect(this.x-1, this.y-1, 2, 2) } } function lineDot(from, to) { stroke("#fff5") strokeWeight(2) line(from.x,from.y, to.x, to.y) } function pyramid(x, y, rot, size) { down = [] down[0] = new dot(2,0) down[1] = new dot(10,1) down[2] = new dot(50,2) up = new dot(250,3) middle = new dot(31250,4) middle.plot() this.center = new dot(6250,5) this.center.plot() y = y + size/3*1 down[0].x = sin(2/3 * PI + rot) * size + x down[0].y = cos(2/3 * PI + rot) * size/4 + y down[1].x = sin(2 * 2/3 * PI + rot) * size + x down[1].y = cos(2 * 2/3 * PI + rot) * size/4 + y down[2].x = sin(3 * 2/3 * PI + rot) * size + x down[2].y = cos(3 * 2/3 * PI + rot) * size/4 + y up.x = x up.y = y - size down[0].plot() down[1].plot() down[2].plot() up.plot() lineDot(down[0], up) lineDot(down[1], up) lineDot(down[2], up) lineDot(down[1], down[0]) lineDot(down[2], down[1]) lineDot(down[0], down[2]) } function recursivePyramid(x = width/2, y = height/2, rot = frameCount/70, size = 250) { if (size > 10) { pyramid(x, y, rot, size) recursivePyramid(x, y - size/2, rot*2, size/2) recursivePyramid(x + size, y + size/2, rot+size*sin(rot/10)/99, size/2) recursivePyramid(x - size, y + size/2, rot+size*sin(rot/10)/99, size/2) } }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).